# Why Word page count always returns 1 in Japanese Operating System

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-interop

But it is works fine in English OS.
Also it is returns the correct value for Excel and Power point document in English OS as well as Japanese OS.
Only the problem am facing page count for Word document in Japanese OS

I have tried three type of code but still i'm getting total Page count as 1 only.

References version: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Version 15.0.0.0
Visual studio : 2013
Microsoft office : 2016

Method :1:-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass appWordPageCount = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document DocPageCount = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic staticPages = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
DocPageCount = appWordPageCount.Documents.Open(fileNames);
wordPageCount = DocPageCount.ComputeStatistics(staticPages, ref missing);  // fetches page count of word files
```

Method :2

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWordPageCount = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document DocPageCount = null;
DocPageCount = appWordPageCount.Documents.Open(wordFile);
wordPageCount = DocPageCount.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Pages.Count;
```

Method :3

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass appWordPageCount = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document DocPageCount = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic staticPages = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
object encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
DocPageCount = appWordPageCount.Documents.Open(ref fileNames, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                    ref encoding, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wordPageCount = DocPageCount.ComputeStatistics(staticPages, ref missing);
```

Thanks in advance for your guidances.

Answer (score 1):

When Word application view mode is "Web layout" then, it always returning page count as 1.
there are three three view mode in it, Read,Print Layout, Web Layout.
So while getting page count of word document , the mode should be in Print Layout.